# how could i use search filter of jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create a list group that will summarize the list of different subject that the teacher have. Now i want to search for the subject in the search but it doesn't work. how could i achieve this using this code?

HTML + PHP codes :

```php
<div class="container">
    <h2>Filterable List</h2>
    <p>Type something in the input field to search the list for specific items:</p>
    <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <br>
    <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
        <?php foreach ($data as $key => $val) { ?>
                <li class="list-group-item"><a>
                    <?php echo $val['name'] ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery codes :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
          var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $("#myList li a").filter(function() {
              $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
          });
      });
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would have to elaborate more on what `...but it doesn't work` means.  I tried your example, though I don't have all the CSS, and when I typed in something, the unmatched names were hidden, only showing what matched. ... Also, where do you close the `container` div? It worked with or without the closing tag, but I added after the input when checking if it made any difference. I used hard-coded names, but it seems that you are missing a `;` after the echo statement in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to filter your search results:
I used some sample data:

```js
  $('#myInput').keyup(function () {
            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.list-group .list-group-item').hide();
            $('.list-group .list-group-item').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Filterable List</h2>
    <p>Type something in the input field to search the list for specific items:</p>
    <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <br>
    <ul class="list-group" id="myList">

        <li class="list-group-item"><a>jan peters</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a>kees peters</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a>marcel test</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a>john doe</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myList li").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase.indexOf(value) > -1;
        }).toggle(true);

        $("#myList li").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase.indexOf(value) < 0;
        }).toggle(false);
    });
});
```